# how call a function when an exception has occurred and the C# program has stopped?

Tags: c#, exception

In a C# program, I want to do some action,when an exception happens; that is when an exception happens and exception window appears, I want to screen capture it and save the image(and other info such as the time and user running the program)of the exception in the db.
Please note that in situation an exception occurs, the program stops until for the user clicks on the button(and if the user clicks on Quit button the app will end).
[image: I intentionally have produced an exception here;but in the real world we do not know when the exception will occur.]
[image: the image of the executable program]

Answer (score 0):

Your error says Unhandled Exception.
Just put your code in try catch block, and handle it accordingly

```
try
{
     int zero = 0;
     double i = (1/zero);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
     //ex contains your error and you can do whatever when you catch it in here
     Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch all unhandled exceptions then you can use the application thread exception method.

In your `program.cs` you need to register the thread exception, and add a method to do your handling.

```
 static class Program
 {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Register your thread exception method here
            Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1(args));
        }


        //This method will then be called and you can handle your exception anyway you wish
        private static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
               //Add your custom handling code here
        }
    }
```